# bit.ly invalid login when accessing from Azure web site

Tags: .net, azure, bit.ly

I have developed a ASP.NET MVC web application that accesses [bit.ly](https://bitly.com/) to shorten a url. I used the .NET NuGet library [Bitly.Net](http://code.google.com/p/bitly-dot-net) as it was referred to in the Bit.ly [Code Reference](http://dev.bitly.com/code_libraries.html).

All worked fine on my local machine, both in Unit Tests and when I ran the Web Application locally. However when I deployed it to Azure it failed. Unfortunately Bitly.Net did not giving a useful error feedback, but as [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31487902/nuget-package-for-bitly-to-shorten-the-links) showed it is easy to write you own, so I did.

Now on calling the [shorten command](http://dev.bitly.com/links.html#v3_shorten) I get an error code of 500 and the error text says 'INVALID LOGIN'.

I am using the depreciated authentication method but looking at the  [documentation on shorten](http://dev.bitly.com/links.html#v3_shorten) is does say I can use that authentication method, and it works locally so its not that. I could swap over to the new OAuth authentication but I think it would have the same problem.

Has anyone accessed the bit.ly API from Azure? Could [CORS](http://dev.bitly.com/cors.html) be an issue?? Any suggestions gratefully received.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I actually emailed bit.ly api support (api@bitly.com) and they kindly came back and they said:

> An INVALID_LOGIN error indicates either you provided an incorrect ‘login’ or incorrect ‘apiKey’ parameter.

What was weird is I had checked the ‘login’ and ‘apiKey’ parameter by logging them and downloading the web.config from Azure. However the bit.ly suppport person suggested I used a [fixed OAuth Token](http://dev.bitly.com/authentication.html) (read the top line that is in bold on the linked page for more about this).

This allows you to get a Token once and then use it in all your requests, which makes using OAuth easy. **I swapped over to OAuth and it worked!**

In case this is useful to someone here is the code, [based on @devfunkd implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31487902/nuget-package-for-bitly-to-shorten-the-links) but updated to:

- Use the fixed OAuth token for validation.
- Use the bit.ly's V3 API, which has a nicer json format.
- It uses Json.NET json deserialiser.
- I made it async.

Note that in the code the field `_bitlyToken` should contain a token created by going to [this page](https://bitly.com/a/oauth_apps). The `_logger` variable holds a logger so that errors are logged.

```
public async Task<string> ShortenAsync(string longUrl)
{
    //with thanks to @devfunkd - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31487902/nuget-package-for-bitly-to-shorten-the-links

    var url = string.Format("https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/shorten?access_token={0}&longUrl={1}",
            _bitlyToken, HttpUtility.UrlEncode(longUrl));

    var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(url);
    try
    {
        var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
        using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
            var jsonResponse = JObject.Parse(await reader.ReadToEndAsync());
            var statusCode = jsonResponse["status_code"].Value<int>();
            if (statusCode == (int) HttpStatusCode.OK)
                return jsonResponse["data"]["url"].Value<string>();

            //else some sort of problem
            _logger.ErrorFormat("Bitly request returned error code {0}, status text '{1}' on longUrl = {2}",
                statusCode, jsonResponse["status_txt"].Value<string>(), longUrl);
            //What to do if it goes wrong? I return the original long url
            return longUrl;
        }
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        var errorResponse = ex.Response;
        using (var responseStream = errorResponse.GetResponseStream())
        {
            var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"));
            var errorText = reader.ReadToEnd();
            // log errorText
            _logger.ErrorFormat("Bitly access threw an exception {0} on url {1}. Content = {2}", ex.Message, url, errorText);
        }
        //What to do if it goes wrong? I return the original long url
        return longUrl;
    }
}
```

I hope that helps someone.

Comment: Comprehensive answer with links very much appreciated.